# SQL Performance comparison for 2 sqls

Tags: sql, left-join

Which query is better in performance aspect ?

### A

```
select users.email
from (select * from purchases where id = ***) A 
left join users on A.user_id = users.id;
```

### B

```
select users.email 
from purchases A 
left join users on A.user_id = users.id where A.id = ***;
```

Basically, I'm thinking A is better.  (But If sql server is optimizing query significantly)

Please explain me which query is better and why. Thanks.

Comment: The answer heavily depends on the database engine. Which one are you using?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.

Comment: Query B provides more optimization freedom to the engine. For example, PostgreSQL 12 will probably optimize both queries equally, but PostgreSQL 11 (an older engine) won't.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm using postgresql

Comment: @LeadDeveloper Which version of PostgreSQL? There are important differences between 11 and 12.

Comment: @TheImpaler I'm using postgresql11 version now. (I've updated version recently from 9.6 to 11).

Comment: @LeadDeveloper Then go for option B. Query A limits the options the optimizer can reach, while query B open more possibilities. Remember that subqueries can be optimization barriers, depending on how smart the optimizer is.

Comment: @TheImpaler Thanks a lot for your help.
I'm not sure why my question is down voted though.
I'm appreciated you response so quickly.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks.

Comment: @TheImpaler: I am pretty sure both queries will result in the same execution plan. Maybe you where thinking about the recent changes for optimizing CTEs? That's something different than optimizing derived tables.

Comment: @LeadDeveloper: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) and you will know. I am pretty sure both result in pretty much the same execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

Almost any database optimizer is going to ignore the subquery.  Why?  SQL queries describer the result set being produced, not the steps for processing it.  The SQL optimizer produces the underlying code that is run.

And most optimizers are smart enough to ignore subqueries and to choose optimal indexes and partitions and algorithms regardless of them.  One except is that some versions of MySQL/MariaDB tend to materialize subqueries -- and that is a performance killer.  I think even that has improved in more recent versions.